# QT List dynamically update

Tags: c++, qt

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "./ui_widget.h"

#include <QPushButton>
#include <array>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);

    data.checkBoxes = {ui->checkBox1, ui->checkBox2, ui->checkBox3, ui->checkBox4, ui->checkBox5};
    data.groupBoxes = {ui->title1, ui->title2, ui->title3, ui->title4, ui->title5};

    ui->percentProgressBar->setValue(0);

    auto ToDoLambda = [=]()
    {
        AddToDo();
    };


    // Connection: Being Able To Add to Do#s to your list!
    connect(ui->addToDoBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, ToDoLambda);

    for(int i = 0; i < data.checkBoxes.size(); i++)
    {

        // Connection: display the percent of tasks we have done
        connect(data.checkBoxes[i], &QCheckBox::stateChanged, [=]()
        {
            ui->percentProgressBar->setValue(PercentDone());
        });
    }

    auto RemoveChecked = [=](int index)
    {
        data.Reset(index);
    };

    auto UpdateForm = [=]()
    {
        const int allBoxesSize = data.groupBoxes.size();

        // Get the amount of boxes which arent disabled
        auto GetBoxes = [=]()->int
        {
            int boxesStillExisting = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < allBoxesSize; i++)
                if(data.groupBoxes[i]->isEnabled() == true)
                    boxesStillExisting++;

            return boxesStillExisting;

        };

        int boxesStillExisting = GetBoxes();
        bool noBoxesExisting = (boxesStillExisting == 0);

        // if all boxes are disabled next to-do at index 0 so the first to do!
        if(noBoxesExisting)
        {
            this->currIndexToDo = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // The Indicees of the boxes disabled and enabled
            std::vector<int> disabled{};
            std::vector<int> enabled{};

            // fill the vector with those indicees

            auto Fill = [&]()
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < allBoxesSize; i++)
                {
                    if(data.groupBoxes[i]->isEnabled() == true)
                        enabled.push_back(i);
                    else
                        disabled.push_back(i);

                }
            };

            Fill();

            // merge those vectors by popping it back to the arr
            auto MergeArrays = [&]()->std::vector<int>
            {
                std::vector<int> mergingProcess {};

                for(int i = 0; i < enabled.size(); i++)
                {
                    mergingProcess.push_back(enabled[i]);
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < disabled.size(); i++)
                {
                    mergingProcess.push_back(disabled[i]);
                }

                return mergingProcess;
            };

            // merge the vectors!
            std::vector<int> merged = MergeArrays();


            auto isAlreadySorted = [=]()->bool
            {
                if(merged == std::vector<int>{0, 1, 2, 3, 4})
                {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            };

            // if its already sorted theres nothing left to do so we just assign the currIndexToDo to the disabled at inde 0
            if(isAlreadySorted())
            {
                this->currIndexToDo = disabled[0];
            }
            else
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < allBoxesSize; i++)
                {
                    if(!data.groupBoxes[0]->isEnabled())
                    {
                        struct ToDoElement
                        {
                            QCheckBox* checkBox;
                            QGroupBox* groupBox;
                            int index;
                        };

                        auto FindNextAvaibaleBoxToGoUp = [=]()->ToDoElement
                        {
                            ToDoElement toDoToReturn = {nullptr, nullptr};

                            for(int i = 0; i < allBoxesSize; i++)
                            {
                                if(data.groupBoxes[i]->isEnabled())
                                    toDoToReturn = {data.checkBoxes[i], data.groupBoxes[i], i};
                            }

                            return toDoToReturn;
                        };

                        ToDoElement elementToReplace = FindNextAvaibaleBoxToGoUp();

                        data.checkBoxes[0]->setText(elementToReplace.checkBox->text());
                        data.groupBoxes[0]->setTitle(elementToReplace.groupBox->title());
                        data.groupBoxes[0]->setEnabled(true);

                        data.Reset(elementToReplace.index);

                        this->currIndexToDo--;

                    }
                }
            }


        }
    };

    connect(ui->removeChecked, &QPushButton::clicked, [=]()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if(data.checkBoxes[i]->isChecked())
            {
                RemoveChecked(i);
            }
        }
        UpdateForm();
    });
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

int Widget::PercentDone()
{
    std::array<QCheckBox*, 5> checkBoxes {ui->checkBox1, ui->checkBox2, ui->checkBox3, ui->checkBox4, ui->checkBox5};

    int len = checkBoxes.size();
    double checksDone = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(checkBoxes[i]->isChecked())
            checksDone++;
    }

    return (int)((checksDone / len) * 100);
}

void Widget::AddToDo()
{
    QString title = ui->titleLineEdit->text();
    QString description = ui->descriptionLineEdit->text();

    if(title == "" || description == "")
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Warning", "Please make sure that the title and the description are both filled in!");
    }
    else
    {
        const int len = 5;

        data.groupBoxes[currIndexToDo]->setTitle(title);
        data.checkBoxes[currIndexToDo]->setText(description);
        data.groupBoxes[currIndexToDo]->setEnabled(true);

        ui->descriptionLineEdit->setText("");
        ui->titleLineEdit->setText("");

        currIndexToDo++;
    }
}
```

Hi
im new to coding in generelle and ive tried the qt framweork now (:
Now i have a problem...
so i have made a to-do list and adding stuff to the to-do list works perfectly fine!
But when i remove stuff i have bumped into some problems. So i wanted to make it so that when i remove an element all the other todo elements dynamically move up accordingly so that the first spot is always taken (when theres still an unchecked todo element).
But it doesnt work...
Well it kinda does but it also doesnt becouse when i remove the first element it works but when i try it on the other elements it doesnt...
Please help

i tried to make it so that the list elements dynamically move up the list but they dont

Comment: Your various lambdas take  all their variables by copy instead of by reference. That is a potential source for state mismatches. Also show the definition&declaration of `data`.

Comment: @Botje hi thank you for the advice heres the definition/ declaration
```cs
struct Data
    {
        std::array<QGroupBox*, 5> groupBoxes {};
        std::array<QCheckBox*, 5> checkBoxes {};

        void Reset(int index)
        {
            groupBoxes[index]->setTitle("Title");
            groupBoxes[index]->setEnabled(false);

            checkBoxes[index]->setChecked(false);
            checkBoxes[index]->setText("Description");
        };
    };

    Data data;
```

Comment: Edit your question instead. A `std::array` is not a good choice for a container that can grow and shrink. Suggest you use a QVector or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @Botje hi botje! i did use a std::array on purpose becouse i didnt know how to dynamically add certain ui elements to a qt from (i still dont know haha). thats why i just made 5 to do elements which are placeholders and then when the user adds to do's i add the info they have provided in the line edits to those place holder elements to turn them into real ones :)